# d3 x-axis not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I'm creating a line chart and my x-axis shows up, however, my y-axis won't display I have no idea why even though it follows the same logic as my x-axis. If anyone could guide me as to where I'm going wrong that would be very helpful.

```
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor))
  .range([dimensions.boundedHeight,0])


const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
  .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])

// 5. Draw data

const lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
  .x(d => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
  .y(d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))

const line = bounds.append("path")
    .attr("d", lineGenerator(dataset))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#c7956d")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0.6)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.8)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)

const yAxisGenerator = d3.axisLeft().tickSize(10)
  .scale(yScale)

const yAxis = bounds.append("g")
  .call(yAxisGenerator)
  .style("transform", `translateY(${
    dimensions.boundedWidth
  }px)`)
  .attr("stroke", "#7C7C7E")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.8)
  
const xAxisGenerator = d3.axisBottom().tickSize(10)
  .scale(xScale)

const xAxis = bounds.append("g")
  .call(xAxisGenerator)
    .style("transform", `translateY(${
      dimensions.boundedHeight
    }px)`)
    .style("stroke", "#7C7C7E")
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("stroke-opacity", 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are translating vertically (translateY) by the width length, should probably be the height instead, most likely it's being drawn outside the container element:

```
  .style("transform", `translateY(${
    dimensions.boundedWidth
  }px)`)
```

Comment: so i've done that and my axis start showing number 50 and 55 then nothing else and it's not starting from 0

Comment: that still sounds like it's being translated by the incorrect value, try setting the transalteY to 0, or removing it altogether for that axis and see how it changes